# Spring NamedParameterJdbcTemplate Cannot Insert NULL using Kotlin

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-jdbc

I am using Kotlin with Spring Boot 2. I am just doing a simple insert with a field that may, or may not be null. However in Kotlin this doesn't appear to be possible using MapSqlParameterSource because the .addValue methods do not accept null or nullable types. This is rather unusual because insert NULL can be a valid use case. This was very straight forward and easy with Java and Spring Boot in the past. Is there a way to get around this, I really don't want to jump through hoops to do something that is simple and straight forward.

```
@Transactional
fun saveSubmittedAnswer(answer: AnswerSubmissionRequest) {

    val query = """INSERT INTO dab.SubmittedAnswer (Id, QuestionId, Answer, SurveyId, ParentQuestionId, TimeTaken
        | VALUES (:id, :questionId, :answer, :surveyId, :parentQuestionId, :timeTaken)
    """.trimMargin()

    answer.answers.forEach { ans ->
        val params: MapSqlParameterSource = MapSqlParameterSource()
                .addValue("id", UUID.randomUUID())
                .addValue("questionId", ans.questionId)
                .addValue("answer", ans.answer)
                .addValue("surveyId", answer.surveyId)
                //.addValue("parentQuestionId", ans.parentId)
                .addValue("timeTaken", ans.timeTaken)

        this.jdbcTemplate.update(query, params)
    }
}
```

All the methods require a non nullable type.

[image]

Comment: Uhg.   I agree with you.  NULL is a valid possible situation and condition but the new hipster trend is that nothing should ever be or return NULL ever.   No matter how much extra boiler plate code that creates for crap like the Optional class in Java and what ever Kotlin's equivalent.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason `MapSqlParameterSource` exists is because Java provides no elegant way to create maps of things. Since we can use `mapOf()` in Kotlin, we probably don't need `MapSqlParameterSource` at all.

If it were me, I would prefer to just use `mapOf()` and avoid `MapSqlParameterSource` entirely:

```
val params = mapOf(
    "id" to UUID.randomUUID(),
    "questionId" to ans.questionId,
    "answer" to ans.answer,
    "surveyId" to answer.surveyId,
    "parentQuestionId" to ans.parentId,
    "timeTaken" to ans.timeTaken
)
jdbcTemplate.update(query, params)
```

However, I agree that this seems like an oversight in the API. It was probably introduced when the nullability annotations were put in to make life easier for Kotlin users.

This seemed to compile for me, but I only tried it in the IDE, and didn't run it:

```
MapSqlParameterSource()
   .addValue("notNullable", myObject.notNulableValue)
   .addValues(mapOf("nullable" to myObject.nullableValue))
```

This works because the `addValues` function takes a `Map<String, ?>` (which, interestingly, is @Nullable).

I'm guessing this is a bug, inadvertently introduced in [this commit](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/87598f48e41d483745aba56cbf4e998c6f6d680c). But again, we have `mapOf()`, and probably don't need this.

Comment: That is an excellent point about using map and that is probably more of the Kotlin way of doing things. I do agree though that the MapSqlParameterSource API for Kotlin is a bug. Wonder if its been reported?

Comment: @greyfox. This has been fixed now : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/commit/d9c63182d90eafaa98d950bf2ae748a050eb7bd8#diff-e638e078242d03891c1357de938b4327